# Access variable based on field in text file, write value to variable based on field in text file

Tags: c#

I have a file with values like this:

```
[Params]
Version=106
Monitor=0
SMode=10000000
Date=20120519
```

In my assembly I have properties that correspond to these fields like this:

```
public static string Version { get; set; }
public static string Monitor { get; set; }
public static string SMode { get; set; }
public static DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I'm iterating through the file like this (_params is a string List with the lines from the [Params] section in the file):

```
foreach (string s in _params)
{
    string[] values = s.Split('=');

}
```

How could I find the variable with values[0] and set it with values[1]?

Edit:

Thanks to Attila, this ended up being my solution. I'm finding the property field by the text in the file, and setting the value from the file. I'm also setting the correct type based on the datatype of the property. I have to do some conversion of some of the strings to make them convert to DateTime datatype:

```
foreach (string s in _params)
{
    string[] values = s.Split('=');

    object myObject = values[0];
    object myValue = values[1];

    if (myObject.ToString() == "Date")
        myValue = ConvertDateStringToDateTime(values[1]);
    if (myObject.ToString() == "StartTime")
        myValue = ConvertStartTimeStringToDateTime(values[1]);
    if (myObject.ToString() == "Length")
        myValue = ConvertLengthStringToTimeSpan(values[1]);

    var type = typeof(HrmParams);
    var field = type.GetProperty(myObject.ToString());

    myValue = Convert.ChangeType(myValue, field.PropertyType);

    field.SetValue(myObject, myValue, null);            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either use reflection (which allows you to access members of objects based on their name at runtime, even if those names are not known at compile time), or create a mapping between known, valid value names in the file and delegates that access (e.g. update) the appropriate variable.

The first approach (reflection) is more general, but at the same time harder to get it right as the compiler/code assistant is not available to help you when you make the connection between the value name in the file and accessing the variable.

The second approach is less error prone (the compiler can flag errors for you), but will limit you to handle only the value names you explicitly specify in the mapping, which means you will have to remember to update the mapping if the valid value names in the file change (e.g. you add a new variable or change its name)

Yet another alternative, which is somewhat of a hybrid between the above two, is to store your variables in a mapping (assuming all of them have the same type (e.g. `string`)) -- this way you can just check the value name from the file against the mapping.  The disadvantage is that the compiler will not be able to help you discover typos (or name changes) when accessing the variables from within the code

Answer (score 1):

A simple switch statement could work:

```
foreach (string s in _params) {
  string[] values = s.Split('=');

  switch (values[0]) {
    case "Version":
      Version = values[1];
      break;
    case "Monitor":
      Monitor = values[1];
      break;
    case "SMode":
      SMode = values[1];
      break;
    case "Date":
      Date = values[1];
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats true, but the file is bigger than i wrote here, and I have much more properties than I wrote here, so its easier to access them programmatically through reflection.